this.focusInsets = null
I made a class in which I adjust the UI for all JSliders to my liking, but when running my program, I intermittently receive the following error:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot read field "left" because "this.focusInsets" is null
at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicSliderUI.calculateContentRect(BasicSliderUI.java:729)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicSliderUI.calculateGeometry(BasicSliderUI.java:698)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicSliderUI$Handler.componentResized(BasicSliderUI.java:1857)
at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.componentResized(AWTEventMulticaster.java:167)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processComponentEvent(Component.java:6447)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6401)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2266)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4996)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4828)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:775)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:714)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:98)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:747)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:744)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
static class CustomSliderUI extends MetalSliderUI {
    private final int customTrackWidth;

    public CustomSliderUI(int customTrackWidth) {
        super();
        this.customTrackWidth = customTrackWidth;
        //this.focusInsets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
        //this.insetCache = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void installUI(JComponent c) {
        super.installUI(c);
        if (this.focusInsets == null) {
            this.focusInsets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void calculateTrackRect() {
        super.calculateTrackRect();
        trackRect.width = customTrackWidth;
        trackRect.x = (slider.getWidth() - customTrackWidth) / 2;
    }

    @Override
    protected Dimension getThumbSize() {
        return new Dimension(30, 30);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintThumb(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        g2.setColor(new Color(0xF3D39B));
        int thumbWidth = 10;
        int thumbHeight = 30;
        int x = thumbRect.x + (thumbRect.width - thumbWidth) / 2;
        int y = 0;
        g2.fillRect(x, y, thumbWidth, thumbHeight);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintTrack(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        int trackHeight = 30;
        trackRect.width = customTrackWidth;

        // Fülle den ausgefüllten Bereich
        int filledWidth = thumbRect.x - trackRect.x + (thumbRect.width / 2);
        g2.setColor(new Color(0xBB7E3B));
        g2.fillRect(trackRect.x, 0, filledWidth, trackHeight);

        // Fülle den nicht ausgefüllten Bereich
        g2.setColor(new Color(0x773A16));
        g2.fillRect(trackRect.x + filledWidth, 0, trackRect.width - filledWidth, trackHeight);
    }
}



  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/pBPtBSIf.png


Please don't include pictures of text. Instead, [edit] your question to include the full stack trace as text.

Hello cmdb,  In the CustomSliderUI class, there should not be the installUI and calculateTrackRect methods, just let MetalSliderUI handle them, or use them but without calling super.

Hello Marce, unfortunately I still get the same error message :(
